# Using string as URL for Wordpress PDF Embedder

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, pdf

I've got an issue with a plugin for Wordpress called PDF Embedder. Also, with concatenating/using a string with document.write. Here's what I'm trying to get to work:

```
<script src="http://nooze.org/wp-content/uploads/scripts/dateGetter.js">
</script>

<script>
  var paperName = m + '-' + d + '-' + y + '-paper.pdf'; //the m, d, and y variables grab the current month, day, and year, that's working fine.
  var paperURL = 'http://nooze.org/wp-content/uploads/documents/papers/' + paperName;
</script>

<script>
  document.write('[pdf-embedder url="' + paperURL + '"]'); //straight up shows nothing :(
</script>
```

This causes PDF Embedder to not work, which led me to believe it was a concatenation/formatting issue. However, even using document.write for a regular ol' paragraph doesn't work.

```
<script>
  document.write('<p>I wish this would work</p>') //spoiler: it doesn't
</script>
```

Even more baffling, however, using document.write with PDF Embedder without concatenation works fine.

```
<script>
  document.write('[pdf-embedder url="http://nooze.org/wp-content/uploads/documents/papers/11-3-17-paper.pdf"]') //works like a charm
</script>
```

So, I'm at my wits end here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle shortcode by javascript , use [wp_ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) to post url as parameter and call and echo `do_shortcode("[pdf-embedder url='$url']")` serverside

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately I'm a total noob and don't understand half the terms you used. I've spent the past half hour or so trying to find definitions with little luck. How exactly would you suggest posting the url as a parameter with wp_ajax? Do I need to create a separate document to handle a script? How do I call and echo something serverside? Sorry for all the questions, I'm super new to this stuff.